# Receives a question mark when trying to see active window open in my program

Tags: c#, winforms

I built Software that grabbing weight and throw into open window where the cursor is. Everything worked out well - I only have one problem annoying
Receives a question mark **(?)** when I open **Word**. and Then the software hangs not recognize the window properly.

when i open Word - i see **Word? - 123.docx** for example. And even if I remove the question mark, the software is still stuck in this case.

my code:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

    private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
    {
        const int nChars = 256;
        StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
        if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
        {
            return Buff.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public void Start(string NAME)
    {
        MSG = lblMSG.Text.Trim();
        IntPtr zero = IntPtr.Zero;
        for (int i = 0; (i < 60) && (zero == IntPtr.Zero); i++) 
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            zero = FindWindow(null, NAME);
        }
        if (zero != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
           .
           .
           .
        }
    }
```

what is the problem ? how to fix it ?

thanks

Comment: You are invoking the 1980s with your pinvoke declaration.  You must insert CharSet = CharSet.Auto so you can properly deal with Unicode strings and avoid the conversion errors that produce ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, strings and `StringBuilder`s are marshalled as Unicode on Windows, so that's not a problem. However, you're calling the ANSI version of the `GetWindowText` method (and the same with `FindWindow`) - that simply isn't going to work. Windows tries to translate everything it can from unicode to ANSI, but it can't do anything with characters outside of the current ANSI codepage.

You need to use `CharSet.Auto`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);
```

This will use the unicode version of `GetWindowText` (`GetWindowTextW`) on unicode systems, and the ANSI version on non-unicode systems.

For comparison, without `CharSet.Auto`, my Word produces

```
??? ?? عربي ,عربى‎‎ [Compatibility Mode] - Microsoft Word
```

With it,

```
ščř řč عربي ,عربى‎‎ [Compatibility Mode] - Microsoft Word
```

My system locale is currently set to Arabic, so Arabic works fine even with the ANSI `GetWindowText` - if I changed back to czech, the `ščř řč` would work fine in ANSI, while the arabic letter would be replaced with question marks. Changing to english would replace *all* of those with question marks, since neither the czech nor arabic letters are supported in the english ANSI codepage.